# Не могу разобраться с udpclient.Receive

Tags: c#, udp

```
bytes = client.Receive(ref endpoint);
```

При такой формулировки просит поменять `receive` на `receiveasync`

[image: вот эту ошибку выдаёт когда меняю]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, чего Вы хотите добиться? Вы хотите использовать асинхронный метод вместо синхронного?

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно вызвать именно асинхронный метод, то можете попробовать вот так:

```
var udpTask = udpClient.RecieveAsync();
udpTask.Wait();
bytes = udpTask.Result.Buffer;
```